# How do i call a function on another function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to call a function does multiplication On another function that accepts two numbers as parameters. i Have tried using constructor and nested function, but to no avail.  i have tried the followings:

```
function Coordinate(a, b) {
    var x, y;
    return {x: a, y: b};
    function multiply(n) {
       x * n;
       y * n;
    }
}
var makeCoordinate = new Coordinate(2,3);
console.log(makeCoordinate.multiple(2));
```

// expected output: 4 6;

Comment: My end game is to create p5.js createVector() and mult() in native javascript, as it is used in this video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kEPixL8JoU&t=3284s  @ 21.25 minutes.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but your method is multiply and you call multiple. Which won't work ofc.
Also, do you want to return a new Coordinate/Vector when doing the multiply or do you want to modify the object itself?

Comment: @ SensThanks for pointing out my typo. i want to modify the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `multiply` to be on the `Coordinate`'s *prototype* so that when you call `new Coordinate`, the instantiated object will have `multiply` as a method. For it to work, you should also set `this.x` and `this.y` instead of returning an object directly:

```js
function Coordinate(a, b) {
  this.x = a;
  this.y = b;
}
Coordinate.prototype.multiply = function(n) {
  this.x *= n;
  this.y *= n;
  return this;
}
var makeCoordinate = new Coordinate(2,3);
console.log(makeCoordinate.multiply(2));
```

Or, if you wanted `multiply` to return just the multiplied coordinates without changing the original object, then return the coordinates alone:

```js
function Coordinate(a, b) {
  this.x = a;
  this.y = b;
}
Coordinate.prototype.multiply = function(n) {
  return [this.x * n, this.y * n];
}
var makeCoordinate = new Coordinate(2,3);
console.log(makeCoordinate.multiply(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer modified two parts:

1. the creation of Coordinate members
2. multiple -> multiply

Hope this help :)

```js
function Coordinate(a, b) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
    this.multiply = function(n) {
       return this.x * n + " " + this.y * n;
    }
}
var makeCoordinate = new Coordinate(2,3);
console.log(makeCoordinate.multiply(2));
```

Comment: @ Terry Wei. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly your console.log is calling multiple, not multiply.

Second, try an approach like this:

```
function Coordinate( a, b )
{
   function multiply( n ) 
   {
      this.x = this.x * n;
      this.y = this.y * n;
      return this;
   }
   var co = { x: a, y : b };
   co.multiply = multiply.bind( co );
   return co;
}
```

Comment: @ Kevmeister68. Thanks alot.

Comment: This is the best answer that satisfied my question. because i want to be referring to the x and y  coordinate of the coordinate function in other to multiply them with the multiply function to move it around the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having clarified in the comments, the (simplest)solution is:

```js
// important code
function Coordinate(a,b) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
    this.multiply = function (n) {
        this.x = this.x*n;
        this.y = this.y*n;        
    }
}

// test code
let coord = new Coordinate(2,3);
console.log("Original Coordinate:");
console.log(coord);
    
coord.multiply(2);
console.log("Changed Coordinate: ");
console.log(coord);
```

You could also put the function in the prototype if you don't want a copy of it in every Coordinate object.

Comment: Thanks again @ Sens.  It is working perfectly. like you siad its the simplest.

Comment: Glad i was able to help @Chuks